# IE7 float:right drops next to float:left

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I've got a list that I'm paginating using some javascript. Everything works absolutely fine in all the browsers I have tested it in, however, one of the directional navigation buttons drops down in IE7 (not in IE8).

[image: screenshot]

The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="index_qa_nav" class="pagination_nav">
    <a class="previous_link" href>Prev</a>
    <a class="page_link first active_page" href style="display: inline-block;">1</a>
    <a class="page_link" href style="display: inline-block;">2</a>
    <a class="page_link" href style="display: inline-block;">3</a>
    <a class="page_link" href style="display: inline-block;">4</a>
    <a class="page_link last" href style="display: inline-block;">5</a>
    <a class="next_link" href>Next</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.pagination_nav {
    text-align: center;
    clear:both;
}

.pagination_nav .previous_link {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 11px;
    background: url(/gfx/pajination/pagination_arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.pagination_nav .next_link {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 11px;
    background: url(/gfx/pajination/pagination_arrows.png) no-repeat -11px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.pagination_nav .page_link {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: url(/gfx/pajination/dots.png) no-repeat 0 1px;
}

.pagination_nav .active_page {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    background: url(/gfx/pajination/dots.png) no-repeat -8px;
}
```

Now I can't seem to figure out why the float:right link won't float on the same level as the links that are float:left. If someone could explain to me why this happen (and why it only happens in IE<7), I would be very grateful. This has been a pain in my butt for far too long.

Comment: Try moving the `.next_link` up into the markup just after `.previous_link`. Should not affect the display in general but might fix the issue here.

Comment: Jon - Create an answer from your comment, and I'll accept it. Moving .next_link next to .previous_link solved the problem.

Comment: Answer created. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reason why this might happen is that the `.page_link` elements that appear in the markup between `.previous_link` and `.next_link` cause the browser to calculate the layout incorrectly.

Since the two links will be floated to each side in the end no matter what (so you know that the presence of `.page_link` elements should not affect the layout), you can simply move `.next_link` up in the markup and place it just after `.previous_link`. The end result will be the same in more modern browsers, but the reordering should help IE7 to reach the same conclusion when laying out the page.

Comment: I've just stumbled on this question, how would you go about this if you CAN'T change the HTML? (I received a couple of down-votes on some questions and have temporarily lost question asking privileges, otherwise I'd ask it as a new question!)

Comment: @RickDonohoe: Depends on the specifics really.

Comment: For what I can fit into a comment.... I basically have a container div (standard page width ~960px) which has 3 buttons inside of it. One is floated left and sits next to the second button which has no float. The third button is floated to the right over on the otherside of the container, but in ie7 it drops. I'm working with code which has been passed on from Drupal development so can't really change it unless its very important. Thanks for the reply mate, and sorry about this commenting way of doing things!!